# adb device not found

Tags: adb, fastboot

When I enter ./adb devices  I get Device not found.  Yet I can successfully unlock my phone via ./fastboot oem unlock.  I can't turn on debugging since my phone is stuck in a bootloop and won't start up.

I am in fastboot mode, and I don't have an sd card.

I'm using a Mac, Samsung Galaxy Nexus (Maguro), SDK, and terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a recovery, such as CWM or TWRP, and download an image. Then use "fastboot boot recovery.img" to boot into the recovery file and reflash a stock ROM, which should solve the problem. Note that even if you don't have a sd card, you should have a partition called /sdcard on the internal memory, which you usually can push files to. Also note that adb access can usually be gotten in recovery. Good luck!